# How to make my USB microphone recognized an audio controller?

Tags: audio, microphone, pipewire

I am trying to get a USB microphone to work on my Gentoo Linux system. I am able to see the device in the output of `lsusb` but my system doesn't seem to be recognizing the device as an audio controller.

I am running pipewire, but have all of the pulseausio, alsa, and jack compatibility packages installed. When running pavucontrol, I do not see the microphone in the Input Devices tab or the Configuration tab.

The (relevant) output of `lsusb`:

```
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 1b3f:2008 Generalplus Technology Inc. USB Audio Device
```

The output of `cat /proc/asound/cards`:

```
0 [HDMI_1         ]: HDA-Intel - HDA ATI HDMI
                      HDA ATI HDMI at 0xf7624000 irq 168
 1 [HDMI           ]: HDA-Intel - HDA ATI HDMI
                      HDA ATI HDMI at 0xf7c20000 irq 170
 2 [Generic        ]: HDA-Intel - HD-Audio Generic
                      HD-Audio Generic at 0xf7a00000 irq 172
```

The output of `arecord --list-devices`:

```
**** List of CAPTURE Hardware Devices ****
card 2: Generic [HD-Audio Generic], device 0: ALC1220 Analog [ALC1220 Analog]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: Generic [HD-Audio Generic], device 2: ALC1220 Alt Analog [ALC1220 Alt Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

`dmesg` output when I connect the microphone:

```
[ 3210.215090] usb 3-3: new full-speed USB device number 6 using xhci_hcd
[ 3210.359059] usb 3-3: New USB device found, idVendor=1b3f, idProduct=2008, bcdDevice= 1.00
[ 3210.359065] usb 3-3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[ 3210.359066] usb 3-3: Product: USB Audio Device
[ 3210.359067] usb 3-3: Manufacturer: GeneralPlus
[ 3210.407191] input: GeneralPlus USB Audio Device as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.2/0000:01:00.0/0000:02:08.0/0000:07:00.3/usb3/3-3/3-3:1.3/0003:1B3F:2008.000C/input/input32
[ 3210.459245] hid-generic 0003:1B3F:2008.000C: input,hidraw7: USB HID v2.01 Device [GeneralPlus USB Audio Device] on usb-0000:07:00.3-3/input3
```

The output of `lsusb -d 1b3f:2008 -v`: https://pastebin.com/5raPSUmV

Comment: Does your kernel configuration include the `CONFIG_SND_USB_AUDIO` option? Does `lsmod | grep snd_usb_audio` report anything?

Comment: @telcoM `CONFIG_SND_USB_AUDIO`is enabled and built into the kernel. `lsmod | grep snd_usb_audio` doesn't output anything, but I think that is because I have `CONFIG_SND_USB_AUDIO=y` in my kernel config.

Comment: Post what happens on `dmesg` when you plug in your microphone, please!

Comment: @MarcusMüller I added the `dmesg` output to the end of my post.

Comment: Thanks! Sadly, I was hoping for any conclusive g hints as to why there's no capture channels. :(

Comment: It might be necessary to review the USB audio descriptors. Use `lsusb -d 1b3f:2008 -v` to display them. The output might be quite long, so you might want to put it into a pastebin somewhere and add a link to it to your question.

Comment: @telcoM  I added a link to the output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out while CONFIG_SND_USB_AUDIO was built into the kernel, I did not update grub so the new kernel was not being used. Updating grub to use the new kernel fixed the issue.

Comment: Excellent :-) Please don't forget to drop by later on (after 48 hours) to accept your answer so this doesn't come up down the line as "Unanswered".